# How to remove the gray layer under inputView swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, inputview

I'm trying to leave the background of my Inputview transparent but I only get it gray.

[image]

The code is:

```
    let fakeField : UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect.zero)
    //1
    InputViewCollection = InputView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 216)) //Intialize custom input view
    InputViewCollection?.delegate = self //delegate
    InputViewCollection?.dataSource = self //datasource

    //2
    InputViewCollection?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    self.fakeField.inputView = InputViewCollection //Assign input view
    self.fakeField.keyboardAppearance = .default
    self.view.addSubview(self.fakeField)
```

How can I leave transparent background of a inputview?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using `inputView`, you have to use the width of the standard keyboard. However, you can set an empty view as the `inputView`, and set your custom keyboard as the `inputAccessoryView` instead. This doesn't have a grey background. The solution would be:

```
self.fakeField.inputView = UIView() // Set an empty, zero-sized view as inputView, in order to remove the standard keyboard
self.fakeField.inputAccessoryView = InputViewCollection // Set your custom keyboard this way instead
```

Comment: WoW thank you so much for this brilliant answer this saved my week :)

Answer (score 0):

try to set alpha value of back Ground View
like `InputViewCollection?.alpha = 0.0`

Comment: if i set InputViewCollection?.alpha = 0.0, then all view is gray. it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`inputViewController`s and `inputView`s seem to have this gray background. However if you use `inputAccessoryViewController` or `inputAccessoryView`, then the background is clear.